# I can't get certain guild with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to take certain roles when bot starting. First i need to take guild but i couldn't achieve it.

```
takenGuild = client.get_guild(myServerID)
```

takenGuild returning None

When i try to loop guilds

```
for guild in client.guilds:
    print(guild.id)
```

it's not printing anything.

My whole code :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')


takenGuild = client.get_guild(123123123123123123)
print(takenGuild.id)

for guild in client.guilds:
    print(guild)
    print(guild.id)
    
    
client.run('Token')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to wait for the bot to be ready you can use this. FYI `bot` is more common now after the updates than `client`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I am running on " + bot.user.name)
    print("With the ID: " + bot.user.id)
    print('Bot is ready to be used')
   # after it is ready do it

    takenGuild = bot.get_guild(123123123123123123)
    print(takenGuild.id)

    for guild in bot.guilds:
        print(guild)
        print(guild.id)
    
    
bot.run('Token')
```