# How do I send a message to a specific discord channel while in a task loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@tasks.loop(seconds=15.0)
async def getAlert():
   #do work here
   channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id_as_int)
   await channel.send("TESTING")

getAlert.start()
bot.run(token)
```

When I print "channel", I am getting "None" and the program crashes saying "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' ".

My guess is that I am getting the channel before it is available, but I am unsure. Anybody know how I can get this to send a message to a specific channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bot cannot get the channel straight away, especially if it's not in the bot's cache. Instead, I would recommend to get the server id, make the bot get the server from the id, then get the channel from that server. Do view the revised code below.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=15.0)
async def getAlert():
   #do work here
   guild = bot.get_guild(server_id_as_int)
   channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id_as_int)
   await channel.send("TESTING")
```

---

(Edit: Including answer from comments so others may refer to this)

You should also ensure that your `getAlert.start()` is in an `on_ready()` event, as the bot needs to start and enter discord before it would be able to access any guilds or channels.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   getAlert.start()
   print("Ready!")
```

---

**Helpful links**:

- [`discord.ext.tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.loop) - discord.py docs
- [`on_ready` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_ready#discord.on_ready) - discord.py docs
- [`bot.get_guild(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) - discord.py docs
- [`guild.get_channel(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_channel#discord.Guild.get_channel) - discord.py docs
- ["I can't get certain guild with discord.py"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63098469/14420546) - Stackoverflow

Comment: Still getting an error:  `channel = guild.get_channel(id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_channel'` When I print the guild as a string it says "None" as well.

Comment: @theCarnage That's odd, is your bot in the server you're trying to access? You could also check if your bot can see guild in general by looping through `bot.guilds`. One other thing to try is to place your task loop in an [`on_ready`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63098469/14420546) event.

Comment: Thank you Bagle. I went ahead and put the call to getAlert.start() in the on_ready event and it is working now. I thought I had to call on_ready() before bot.run(token), but in fact you dont. Thanks again for your help.