# Discord py 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members' (With Enabled Intents)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
guild = client.get_guild(sampleid)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
        print(f"Ready the bot {client.user} is there")
        print (guild.members[1])
```

When I use this code, I get the described error. I searched for it already, and the suggested solution was to enable the intents, which I then did in the code and on the dev portal, but the error is still the same.
Any suggestions why?

Comment: Check if `sampleid` is the id you want it to be. Likely the call returns `None` for `guild` if that id is invalid

Comment: Done and yes its the ID of my server ,where the Bot is on

Comment: You cannot get guilds until the client is ready.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't get certain guild with discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090280/i-cant-get-certain-guild-with-discord-py)

Comment: yes so its a big diffrence if i use bot or client

Comment: See the dupe target again. You can't do anything with discord until the client is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the invocation of `get_guild` into the `on_ready` event.
Your client is not fully loaded until this event, and most of it's methods will not work.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
guild = None

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global guild
    guild = client.get_guild(sampleid)
    print(f"Ready the bot {client.user} is there")
    print (guild.members[1])
```